# Login with Facebook in my App?

Tags: android, android-facebook

I'm creating a login from Facebook in my app. My app is a list of product prices and I want my user can enter with your email/password to insert in my WebService and return prices to your email.

The problem is when I click on LoginButton it's open a LoginActivity of Facebook to loggin and I want open a AlertDialog with EditText email/password to user type the informations and after I will do login in facebook and if login facebook is all right I get the email/password typed in EditText and make send to my WebService.

Reading the documentations of Facebook API I see this.

*The Facebook SDK for Android provides methods to implement Facebook Login for your app. The SDK provides Facebook Login support for the these common scenarios:
Your app uses only Facebook Login to authorize people using your app.
Your app provides two login options: Facebook Login and your own login mechanism.
Your app uses your own login initially and Facebook Login is an option to switch on certain social features.
In cases (1) and (3), the Facebook SDK provides a UserSettingsFragment class that can be hosted by your login activity to display the Facebook login/logout button. In case (2), the Facebook SDK provides a LoginButton class that provides a button you can drop into your UI. The LoginButton class maintains the session state and is used to log people in and out.*

There's any way to do it ?

Like this

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you want to pass information you collect from the dialog box into the Facebook login box. As far as I know this isn't possible. The Facebook SDK can detect if Facebook is installed on the phone and authenticate that way, or it will popup a dialog box for the user to login. I'm pretty sure the reason for this has to do with security concerns.

Comment: the true is I want open a Dialog where user type email/password of Facebook, like this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/br/library/x-androidfacebookapi/fig04.jpg after user type email/password the dialog is dismiss and login Facebook